# cant seem to get sounddevice module to change to the sound device i want to

Tags: python, audio

im making a type of "aux switch" and I decided that i was going to use python module sounddevice to do that and I use it BUT i cant seem to get it to use the sound device that i want it too. every time that i try to change it for some reason it dose not work

```
import argparse
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy  # Make sure NumPy is loaded before it is used in the callback
assert numpy  # avoid "imported but unused" message (W0611)
print(sd.query_devices())

sd.check_input_settings(device= "VoiceMeeter Aux Output (VB-Audio VoiceMeeter AUX VAIO), Windows DirectSound")
sd.check_output_settings(device= "CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable), Windows DirectSound ")
def int_or_str(text):
    
    """Helper function for argument parsing."""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l', '--list-devices', action='store_true',
    help='show list of audio devices and exit')
args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.list_devices:
    print(sd.query_devices())
    parser.exit(0)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[parser])
parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--input-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='')
parser.add_argument(
    '-o', '--output-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='output device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--channels', type=int, default=2,
    help='number of channels')
parser.add_argument('--dtype', help='audio data type')
parser.add_argument('--samplerate', type=float, help='sampling rate')
parser.add_argument('--blocksize', type=int, help='block size')
parser.add_argument('--latency', type=float, help='latency in seconds')
args = parser.parse_args(remaining)


def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    outdata[:] = indata

try:
    
    with sd.Stream(device=(args.input_device, args.output_device),
                   samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize=args.blocksize,
                   dtype=args.dtype, latency=args.latency,
                   channels=args.channels, callback=callback):
        print('#' * 80)
        print('press Return to quit')
        print('#' * 80)
        input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    parser.exit('')
except Exception as e:
    parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy  # Make sure NumPy is loaded before it is used in the callback
assert numpy  # avoid "imported but unused" message (W0611)
print(sd.query_devices())
inpdev = "VoiceMeeter Aux Output (VB-Audio VoiceMeeter AUX VAIO), Windows DirectSound"
outdev = "CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable), Windows DirectSound "
def int_or_str(text):

    """Helper function for argument parsing."""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l', '--list-devices', action='store_true',
    help='show list of audio devices and exit')
args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.list_devices:
    print(sd.query_devices())
    parser.exit(0)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[parser])
parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--input-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='')
parser.add_argument(
    '-o', '--output-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='output device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--channels', type=int, default=2,
    help='number of channels')
parser.add_argument('--dtype', help='audio data type')
parser.add_argument('--samplerate', type=float, help='sampling rate')
parser.add_argument('--blocksize', type=int, help='block size')
parser.add_argument('--latency', type=float, help='latency in seconds')
args = parser.parse_args(remaining)


def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    outdata[:] = indata

try:

    with sd.Stream(device=(inpdev, outdev),
                   samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize=args.blocksize,
                   dtype=args.dtype, latency=args.latency,
                   channels=args.channels, callback=callback):
        print('#' * 80)
        print('press Return to quit')
        print('#' * 80)
        input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    parser.exit('')
except Exception as e:
    parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```